# Records sorted in levelDB in particular levels or the whole database?

Tags: leveldb

In case of levelDB, are the records in a sorted format in just the specific levels or the whole database is in a sorted form ?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Every level is sorted separately i.e level1 keys might be 1,3,7,9 and level2 2,4,5,6,8,10